# InDesign Load Balancing and Queueing Customizing XML-Reponse

Tags: xml, response, load-balancing, message, adobe-indesign

Currently we are implementing the InDesign LBQ into our application. This is supposed to replace our old custom made LBQ'er and provide us with more requested functionality.

Except we are wondering if the XML response sent back to the client by the server is customizable. For example, if a String in an InDesign poster text block is too long and doesn't fit, send this flaw back in an error message in the response so the client who sent in the job will see this error along with the result (It still gets the result, since it will still be made succesfull but the client will know something isn't the way it's supposed to be and will be able to adjust this).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can return a custom error and the result of the script at the same time.

I suggest you trap the error in your InDesign script, add and return it with the result XML as an extra error node?

Comment: This is pretty much what i meant, does this mean it is possible to add a xml node which can contain the error generated by our check to the result send by InDesign?

Comment: You have control over what you return, could be a number, string or xml. So you can build your xml, add  error node if you need it and return it back to the soap request. So, return "<error>25</error>"; at the end of your script should do it.

Comment: And this response, will this be send directly to the client, or to the load balancer after which it will go to the client?

Comment: It is going to the client, but if load balancer receives it first, I am not sure.